# Posso me tornar um programador estudando Python usando QPython?

Tags: python

Por exemplo, se possível ganhar dinheiro.
Tenho version QPython 2.7 e 3

Comment: Você pode se tornar um bom programador, usando qualquer linguagem, basta ser bom no oque faz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode sim. Principalmente se você considerar que fazer programas torna a pessoa um programador.

Se tornar um programador de qualidade já é outra coisa. É processo longo e de dedicação. Coisa que poucas pessoas fazem. Mesmo assim muitas delas conseguem ganhar dinheiro com isto e até se acham programadores "profissionais". Em certo sentido são mesmo, já que recebem pelo trabalho. Algumas pessoas se iludem também. Ganhar dinheiro ou não envolve outro tipo de habilidade.

Mas que fique claro que ser programador não é apenas aprender uma linguagem de programação. Se prepare para muito trabalho, muito estudo ou se prepare para ser considerado um enganador na indústria. O que não fará você ficar sem emprego, mesmo que seja um de baixa qualidade.

Mas respondendo sua dúvida objetivamente, o QPython é uma das implementações da linguagem Python que permite fazer aplicações para Android. É uma forma de fazer isto. Até onde eu sei há limitações no momento. Eu diria que poucas pessoas com experiência na área usaria tal produto para fazer algo sério agora. Talvez para começar aprender sirva.

Alguns dirão que não é a mais recomendada, mas se é isto que você quer começar, pode ir em frente que tecnicamente é possível, basta se dedicar. Mas considere olhar para alternativas. Começar fazer algo que você não tem ideia do que é, só porque tem ele à disposição é começar bem errado.

Se deseja fazer algo sério, o caminho é outro, talvez usando a implementação tradicional de Python.

Comment: Pra começar, baixei uma apostila básica de Python, estimei que iria terminar ela em 30 dias, pois quero reter todo o conteúdo dela, lendo 5 páginas por dia, revisando e exercitando elas, estudadas no dia. A apostila tem 157 páginas. Não quero esquecer de nada. Depois que terminar baixo uma apostila de POO, e em seguida vejo o que posso fazer. Quero ficar afiado na linguagem.

Comment: Está no caminho certo. Não se preocupe com OOP no começo, isto menos importante do que as pessoas acham. Tem sua importância. Mas muita gente abusa, usa quando não precisa. Complica o software s/ motivo.

Comment: OK! Valeu pela ajuda! ;)